# Relation between a Quasistatic and a reversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, reversibility

Why is it that if a process is [reversible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_%28thermodynamics%29), it is [quasi-static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process)? Does it mean that then the process is also non-dissipative if it is quasistatic?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78405/2451 and links therein.

Comment: _Does it mean that a finite process can't be reversible?_ Reversibility is an ideal process (you always have entropy creation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a quasistatic process that is not reversible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297386/is-there-a-quasistatic-process-that-is-not-reversible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reversible process is defined as an ideal process, without friction, losses and entropy production. In general, such an ideal system can be represented most closely by a process with very low velocity. For example, compressing a gas piston has to be done very slowly to minimize losses and approach an ideal reversible system. In practice however, this is virtually impossible, and losses (even if very small losses) are inevitable.